# How to integrate Like feature in iPhone SDK 3.1 with Facebook sharing app

Tags: iphone, ios

I am new to iPhone development. I’ve added Facebook sharing functionality and I also want to add the Like feature from Facebook. I’ve followed one of the examples; it works if Facebook sharing functionality hasn’t been implemented, because some files create contradiction (specifically `FBRequest.h`). But I want to add both sets of functionality at the same time. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are new then its not a issue. Everybody have same brain. So its not a big issue. Check

this link: `http://www.raywenderlich.com/1626/how-to-post-to-a-users-wall-upload-photos-and-add-a-like-button-from-your-iphone-app`

First of all understand it then implement it. I know you will surely implement this in Your

App. Best of luck.

Comment: i understand this code but after running the code when i press login button then open a facebook login page but it cannt open any facebook login address.